# My working directory, files, and urls

Tags: java, toolkit, working-directory

I have a convergence of needs revolving around where my data files are.  The current application has all class and data files in a JAR (building using Eclipse IDE).

I've noticed there seem to be a variety of ways in which people get this information.  I need the path for where my image files are (graphics).  I also need it as a URL o use the toolkit call.

```
Toolkit tk = frame.getToolkit();
image = tk.getImage(url.toFile());
```

But I am having trouble with creating the URL or something.  I have tried a few different methods. At this point, I keep data files next to class files in the file system.  I am adding another function to what I do - strip the /bin directory off when running in debug.

```
// in class BwServices at init:
try {
    rootDataPath = BwServices.class.getProtectionDomain()
        .getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
    rootDataPath = URLDecoder.decode(rootDataPath, "UTF-8");
        fileSystemAccess = true;
} 
if(rootDataPath.endsWith("/bin/"))  
    rootDataPath = rootDataPath.substring(0, rootDataPath.length() - 4);
```

Later on... I go to get images, and some calls don't work, I don't know why

I've tried two things....

```
// 1
String s = "file://" + rootDataPath + d.toString() + fileName;   
url = frame.getClass().getResource(s);

// 2
    try {
        url = new URL(s);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        trace("getImage - can't get url: " + s);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Either of which has problems.
I have calls to get images from different places.  The 'frame' is the parent frame throughout the execution, in class BwFrame.

My path comes out like this in any attempts...

rootDataPath: /C:/Users/Markgm/Documents/DEV/workspace/bwp/

So, I'm looking for ways to open either FileInputStream or URLs for the toolkit, for files relative to where the class file is (and with some trick for when in debug).  For a client-side app this is what this is.  Someday, I might want to run this as an Applet, but I don't know where the image files will have to be. (50x75 playing cards and a few button images)  Any help or advice is appreciated!

TIA,
Mark

Comment: Well, I know I can say this.  The getClass().getResource(String) call which returns a URL is giving me a problem. I'm in debug, which puts the class files in a subdir called 'bin'.  But I go after image files in another subdir called gfx.  So, I see getResource("gfx/s.png") does not work. getResource("/gfx/s.png") does work. It works with a leading slash.  I cannot get it to work with a valir pathname starting with the drive letter, as returned from in init(), from class.getProtectionDomain()   .getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();

Comment: Seems like you are having problems with your IDE. Regardless of the subdirs where your images are, they should be added to your classpath and getResource() will work fine.

Comment: " Regardless of the subdirs where your images are, they should be added to your classpath and getResource() will work fine "  --------- Do you do that with all your resource subdirs?

Comment: In order to use the classloader to look up a resource it has to be on the classpath, so yes - you either add them or just package them in the same directory/jar as the generated classes (the sources can still reside in separate trees).

Comment: Regarding the leading slash - getResources() from a class looks up relative to the class package, so if you need to specify absolute path you need leading slash. getResources() from a classloader expects absolute path, and in this case you *must not* specify leading slash (it is a poor API).

Answer (score 1):

```
Toolkit tk = frame.getToolkit();
```

Don't use `Toolkit` to load images, since Java 1.4.  Use `ImageIO.read(String/File/URL)` instead, which is a blocking method that ensures the entire image is loaded before returning.

```
image = tk.getImage(url.toString());
```

And there is an actual problem.  Once you have an `URL` (or `File`) object, don't toss it away and use the `String` representation.  Even more importantly, don't provide a `String` that is supposed to represent a `File`, but actually represents an `URL`!

I didn't read the rest of that mess of code snippets (in the question or follow-up 'answer'), you might look to post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) in future.

Comment: OK, well, I've got Toolkit working, in my answer-code above, with a full pathspec.  Nextly, in the top example it was url.getFIle() and a typo in the posting (to toString()) - neither worked.  I didn't make an SSCCE due to the code involved, but wanted to see what anyone would say about how they access files in/out of the jar file on a client-side app.  My answer posting also uses a MediaTracker to wait for the image to load.  Thank you for the tip about ImageIO.read(), which I guess would work with my rootDataPath + filename above?

Comment: *"which I guess would work"* Stop guessing & read the JavaDocs.

Comment: This is what I've got working all around.  The String file has the full local pathsepc & filename in it....... image = ImageIO.read(new File(file)); The pathsepc is from rootDataPath, as made during init in the code in my answer posting.

Comment: Correction: I don't have images coming out of the JAR file - that was my mistake of another copy of image subdirs resolving that.  I haven't got code that goes into a jar without using URL.

Comment: I'd like to mark this as answered.  ImageIO.read( URL ) works for pulling images from the JAR file as "/imageDir/filename".  A local pathspec+filename works when not in a JAR, allowing me to strip off bin/ as well when in debug.  When I learn packaging in Eclipse, I'll probably get it right without these kludges.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of using URLs at all, which started with the use of pasted code.  The behavior of URLs changed, as did everything, when running from a class file versus running from a JAR file.  So I have code here that shows some of what I ended up doing, and comments to what happens (class file or jar file), and I also got the adjustment for debug time to work (snipping off bin/ from the end).

```
        // root path - starts with jar file or pathspec
    try {
        rootDataPath = BwServices.class.getProtectionDomain()
                    .getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        rootDataPath = URLDecoder.decode(rootDataPath, "UTF-8");
        if(rootDataPath.endsWith("BwPlayer.jar"))
            rootDataPath = rootDataPath.substring(0, rootDataPath.length() - 12);
        fileSystemAccess = true;
    } catch(SecurityException e) {
        trace("No file system access: " + e.getMessage());
        messageBox(frame, "BwServices", "Cannot access file system");
        rootDataPath = "";
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        trace("Jar URL decode exception: "+ e.getMessage());
    } 
    if(rootDataPath.endsWith("/bin/"))  // remove bin/ portion if in debug
        rootDataPath = rootDataPath.substring(0, rootDataPath.length() - 4);
    trace("rootDataPath: "+rootDataPath);
```

Above: from init() time.  Below, a getImage() function, including extra debug-related lines.  Note: url.getFile() doesn't directly work for 2 reasons - one is it has the file:/ when out of a jar, and the other because it won't take a full pathspec beneath its pre-stated root /.

```
    static public Image getImage(Directory d, String fileName) {
    Image image = null;
    String s = d.toString() + fileName;
    /*
    // Note: Start with / required for this url call (w/o full pathsepc)
    URL url = parentFrame.getClass().getResource("/" + s);
    if(url == null) {
         trace(s + " - null url ");
         return null;
    }
    */
    String file = rootDataPath + s; // url.getFile();
    // end note
    String t = s = "getImage(" + file + ") ";

    Toolkit tk = parentFrame.getToolkit();
    if(tk == null)
        s = s + "NULL tk ";
    else {
        try {
            // full pathspec needed here 
            // url.getFile() returns with file:/ when running from the .jar file
            //  but not when running from .class file (so don't use it)
            s = t = "getImage(" + file + ") ";
            image = tk.getImage(file); //url.getFile());
            MediaTracker media = new MediaTracker(parentFrame);
            media.addImage(image, 0);
            try {
                media.waitForID(0);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                s = s + e.getMessage();
            }       
            if(image == null) {
                // image = null;
                s = s + "NULL image ";
            } else if(image.getHeight(parentFrame) < 1) {
                s = s + "invalid height";
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            s = s + e.getMessage();
        }
    } 

    if(! s.equals(t)) {
        s = "file=" + file + "\n" + s;
        s = "rootDataPath=" + rootDataPath + "\n" + s;
        messageBox(parentFrame, "getImage()", s);
    }
    return image;
}
```

Comment: As I commented elsewhere, I had not really finished getting images out of the JAR alright, due to having image dirs there as well.  I have it working as above, but where if making a URL works using "/" as root (plus in-jar dir/filename), then I use the URL, otherwise I use the filename. That is working both ways (or now 'all ways').